# Read email and store data using Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, tmail

I'm currently working on a project that requires: 
1)Ruby reads the email
2)It stores the data, i.e project name from the email. 
3) Project hours corresponding to project name

I've looked through the internet but I found methods to print the body of the email, nothing that'd give me a way to parse email and store data in an array.

I'm not sure if Tmail has any methods that specifically address my question.

Please let me know if more details are required- I will try to clarify.

Thanks in advance!

I'm not sure if it's even possible to do this. Anyone had any experience with something like this?

Comment: is there a predefined format for the message (e-mail) body? If yes, post it.

Comment: It's going to be how an email is formatted usually. The email will be in Outlook. I might have found an answer- not sure yet. Will post the entire thing once I'm ready. Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you need to parse out things from the message body, you should know what to look for in advance => a predefined template. when you say "_It's going to be how an email is formatted usually_", do you mean it is going to be a free text format with no predefined template?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes- I think I know how to approach the problem. A friend of mine suggested that I use pattern matching and have the program look for, as you said, a predefined template. It's my first time taking a programming class, so I was a little worried, I wouldn't know what to do. But thanks very much! :)